# How to convert String containing date and time to LocalTime variable

Tags: java, time, simpledateformat, java-time, localtime

I was converting a sequence of `String`s which contained three different times
 **Start, end and duration**
 `"00:01:00,00:02:00,00:01:00"`

to `LocalTime` variables:

```
for (final String str : downtime) {
      final DependencyDownTime depDownTime = new DependencyDownTime ();
      final String[] strings = str.split (",");

      if (strings.length == 3) {

           LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse (strings[0]);
           depDownTime.setStartTime (start);

           LocalTime end = LocalTime.parse (strings[1]);
           depDownTime.setEndTime (end);

           Duration duration = Duration.between (start, end);
           depDownTime.setDuration (duration);
           downTimes.add (depDownTime);
      }
  }
```

The `String` being parsed has changed and now includes a date.     `2017-09-13 00:01:00`

How do I remove the date string keeping only the time?

I have tried to use the `SimpleDateFormat`

```
final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat ("HH:mm:ss");
LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse (dateFormat.format (strings[0]));
depDownTime.setStartTime (start);
```

But I get a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `DateTimeFormatter`, then parse it to a `LocalDateTime` and extract the `LocalTime` from it:

```
String input = "2017-09-13 00:01:00";
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

LocalTime time = LocalDateTime.parse(input, fmt).toLocalTime();
```

Or parse it directly to a `LocalTime`, using the `from` method:

```
LocalTime time = LocalTime.from(fmt.parse(input));
```

Or (even simpler):

```
LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(input, fmt);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use DateTimeFormatter(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter) and LocalDateTime

```
    String s = "2017-09-13 00:01:00";

    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    LocalTime start = LocalDateTime.parse(s,dtf).toLocalTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

You may just use [String#split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) if you are sure the format of string is already the same.

```
String s = "2017-09-13 00:01:00";
String[] frags = s.split(" ");
System.out.println(frags[frags.length - 1]);
```

Output:

```
00:01:00
```

Add some checks if you need.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the new java datetime API. I.e. configure the right parser. Here it is:

```
String original = "2017-09-13 00:01:15";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .parseCaseInsensitive()
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
        .appendLiteral(' ') // this is what you won't find among the default formatters
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
        .toFormatter();
LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(original, formatter); // it's cool now
System.out.println(time); // prints 00:01:15
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you ::

Or you can use the split function as written in another answer.

Here your string has been converted to date and calendar objects. Now you can do anything with the objects.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
        String timestamp = "2017-09-13 00:01:00";
        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-mm HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = format.parse(timestamp);
        System.out.println(date);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);

        System.out.println(date.getTime());
        System.out.println(date.getHours());
        System.out.println(date.getMinutes());
        System.out.println(date.getSeconds());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` is fixed, this would probably be the fastest answer so far, since it avoids any kind of added string parsing or splitting:

`LocalTime.parse(strings[0].substring(11))`

Comment: I don't think so. Short comment and it's readable and understandable. However it is probably error prone, who would notice if that 11 should actually be a 10. ;)